# add content to bugreport

Tags: android, adb

adb bugreport

is generating a *.zip file which contains a lot of reports that can be analyzed.
Is it possible to add own files which are on the target to the bugreport so that the *.zip file will contain those files?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `zip` by default on android so unless you install it or create an app that can manipulate zip files you should do it on the side that's running `adb` (i.e. your computer).

You can create a script like this:

```sh
adb bugreport mybugreport
adb pull /path/to/myfile1
adb pull /path/to/myfile2
zip mybugreport.zip myfile1 myfile2
```